# Store calculation in database using variables submitted in a form

Tags: ruby, forms, variables, model

I'm submitting a simple form  with variables that are named in the database.

I am trying to:

1. Store the submitted variables in the database (which works fine)
2. Run a calculation, then store that value into the database

No matter what I try I either get an error or `'nil'` (upon @kcmil.inspect) as my result for `@kcmil`. I'm assuming in my current code i'm not passing the variables to the model, but it doesn't work even when it's in the controller.

I'm at a loss here. My variables that are submitted in the form store just fine as expected. I just want to be able to use submitted variables from a form (that are also database items that get stored upon submission) and before saving to the database (or after, should it matter?) run a calculation and store the result in a database item (that is not previously called in or saved from the form). Does that make sense? Any help or hints are GREATLY APPRECIATED!!

**Here are my current calculators_controller create and edit actions:**

```
  def create
   @calculator = Calculator.new(calc_params)
   if @calculator.save
      flash[:notice] = "Calculation created successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def update
    @calculator = Calculator.find(params[:id])
    if @calculator.update_attributes(calc_params)
     flash[:notice] = "Calculation updated successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'index', :id => @calculator.id)
    else
      render('edit')
    end
  end

private

 def calc_params
      params.require(:calculator).permit(:subsection, :amps, :volts, :distance, :vdrop, :phase, :kcmil, :section_id)
 end
```

**Here's my model**

```
class Calculator < ActiveRecord::Base

before_create :kcmil_calc

def kcmil_calc
   if @phase == 1
          self.kcmil = ((13 * @distance.to_i * @amps.to_i ) / @vdrop.to_i).round(2)
       else
          self.kcmil = ((12.9 * @distance.to_i  * @amps.to_i ) / @vdrop.to_i).round(2)
      end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I HAVE IT! I HAVE IT!

```
before_update :defaults

def defaults
    if self.phase == 1
        self.kcmil = ((12.9 * distance * amps) / vdrop).round(2)
    else
        self.kcmil = ((13 * distance * amps) / vdrop).round(2)
    end
end
```

solved it! I had to call `self.phase` instead of `@phase` and change `before_create` to `before_update` to get it to work . No change in the controller required. Dang - one simple @! I also removed the to_i because it's not needed since my views prevent me from submitting anything other than integers.